# Link (a) in GridView is problematic?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an (a) in my grid view and it does not compile:

```asp
  <asp:GridView ID="gvProjects" runat="server" OnSorting="gvProjects_Sorting"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
            GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="ProjectTitle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                           <a href="#myModal" id="remove_emp_btn" onclick="go('projectFrame','ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>')" 
                               runat="server" data-toggle="modal">'<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>'</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Am I forced to use asp controls or is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks

It says the server tag is not well formed.

The problem seems to be:

```asp
 onclick="go('projectFrame','ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>')"
```

Comment: You do have a closing `</Columns>` and `</asp:GridView>`, right?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the onclick it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap all the content of `onclick` attribute in the server tags `<%# %>` and the attribute `runat="server"` can be removed. Also, double quote character must be escaped:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProjects" runat="server" OnSorting="gvProjects_Sorting"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
GridLines="None">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="ProjectTitle">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <a href="#myModal" id="A1" onclick='<%# "go(\"projectFrame\", \"ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id=" + Eval("ProjectID").ToString() + "\" )" %>'
                    data-toggle="modal">'<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>'</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Alternative:

Using the second parameter of the Eval method to format the string makes the markup easier to read.

```
   <a href="#myModal" id="remove_emp_btn" onclick='<%# Eval("ProjectID", "go(\"projectFrame\", \"ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id={0}\")") %>'
                data-toggle="modal">'<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>'</a>
```

Comment: It keeps complaining about non well formed tag

Answer (score 0):

I've never had luck with putting eval's in the middle of text.  I often resorted to rendering this way:

```
"<%= "go('projectFrame','ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id=" + (string)Eval("ProjectID") %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the <%# %> syntax and remove the runat=server:

```
 <a href="#myModal" id="remove_emp_btn"  OnSorting="gvProjects_Sorting"
                           onclick='<%# "go('projectFrame','ProjectViewFrame.aspx?id=" + Eval("ProjectID").ToString() + ")" %>'
                               data-toggle="modal">'<%# Eval("ProjectTitle") %>'</a>
```